# sed replace bbcodes with regex

Tags: regex, linux, sed, bbcode

I want to replace specific BBCodes like

```
[youtube]http://youtube.com/watch?v=00000000000[\youtube]
[youtube]http://youtu.be/00000000000[\youtube]
[youtube]http://youtu.be/00000000000/[\youtube]
[youtube]http://youtube.com/watch?v=00000000000&something=wrong[\youtube]
[youtube]youtube.com/watch?v=00000000000[\youtube]
```

to

```
[MEDIA=youtube]00000000000[\MEDIA]
```

My current pattern get no matches:

```
 sed -i 's/\[youtube\]\(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|.*\)\(www\.|.*\)youtu\(be\.com|\.be\)\(\/watch\?v=|\/\)\([a-zA-Z0-9-]{11}\)\(.*\)\[\/youtube\]/\[MEDIA=youtube\]\5\[\/MEDIA\]/g' text.txt
```

What do you think about it? Where could be my fault?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the expected output in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with awk (put it in file.awk and file.txt is your input).

awk -f file.awk file.txt

**file.awk**

```
BEGIN {
    # a list of patterns
    lp = \
    "http://youtube.com/watch?v= http://youtube.com/watch?v=/ " \
    "http://youtu.be/ http://youtube.com/watch?v=/ " \
    "youtube.com/watch?v="

    # escape ?
    gsub("?", "\\?", lp)

    # add [youtube]
    media="youtube"
    gsub("[ ^]", " \\[" media "]", lp)

    # make array of patterns
    split(lp, pat, " ")
}

{
    for (i in pat) {
       n=split($0, arr, pat[i])
       if (n>1) {
           # remove rest of the string
           gsub("[/[&].*", "", arr[2])
           printf "[MEDIA=%s]%s[MEDIA]\n", media, arr[2]
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
sed -n '/^\[youtube\]/{s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)*.*/[MEDIA=youtube]\1[\\MEDIA]/p}' input
```

Comment: Your solution works great but the zeros are placeholder. An original URL has a random string like 2DfefdfFDfb

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '\|^\[([^]]+)\](http://)?[^/]*/(watch\?v=)?(.{11}).*\[\\\1\]$|s//[MEDIA=\1]\4[\\MEDIA]/' file
```